# Where to Put Code Configuring Persistent Store for Migration

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, core-data-migration

I have a Mac App already created and distributed on the App Store to many customers, and I need to add an attribute to the Core Data Model. I read the documentation provided by Apple, available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vdUd.png).

However, it gives this block of code to enable automatic migration:

```
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = <#The coordinator#>;
NSURL *storeURL = <#The URL of a persistent store#>;
NSDictionary *optionsDictionary =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                    forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];

NSPersistentStore *store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:<#Store type#>
                                configuration:<#Configuration or nil#>
                                URL:storeURL
                                options:optionsDictionary
                                error:&error];
```

.. And I have no idea where to put that. Someone mentioned (in another thread) that it goes into a PersistentStoreCoordinator, however, I simply used the default Cocoa App Template with "Use Core Data for Storage" enabled. I had to create my own AppDelegate and never saw anything about a PersistentStoreCoordinator (and still don't. I've tried creating a new app just to check). Any help here? I'm new to Cocoa but my app works perfectly fine without a PersistentStoreCoordinator, which is why I haven't implemented one yet.. I do have an AppDelegate I created, but when I put this code in there it throws many errors. HELP :/

EDIT (for nick): Here is the new code:
[image]

And my header file:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: Core Data relevant header and methods.

**Application Delegate Header - Core Data relevant parts**

```
@interface CoreDataFirstStepsAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
{    
     // ...
@private
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext_;
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel_;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}

// ...

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

**Application Delegate Implementation - Core Data relevant parts**

```
/**
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {

    if (managedObjectContext_ != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext_;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext_ = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext_ setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext_;
}


/**
 Returns the managed object model for the application.
 If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel_ != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel_;
    }
    NSString *modelPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CoreDataFirstSteps" ofType:@"momd"];
    NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:modelPath];
    managedObjectModel_ = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
    return managedObjectModel_;
}


/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataFirstSteps.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {

        NSError *error;
        NSURL *storeURL = storeURL;
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = persistentStoreCoordinator_;
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

        if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                               configuration:nil
                                         URL:storeURL
                                     options:options 
                                       error:&error]) 
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }       
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}

/**
 Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Comment: @Nick: thanks for the reply. Actually I had to create my own AppDelegate, there wasn't one included. I pasted the first section of your code into my implementation, and put the code apple provided in the brackets. Upon runtime, it threw errors all over the place. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Nick: I edited my post to show the screenshot. Thanks for your help so far - any more help would be GREATLY appreciated

Comment: Please create a clean templated app which uses core data and then look at the app delegate. It's really straightforward how core data is being inserted into an app. Move the relevant methods to your app. The code you provided won't compile cause you have placeholders like `<#Store type#>` in it, which have to be substituted with real code. You can identify them with the light blue background.

Comment: I've altered the code of the `- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {...}` and put in apple's example code. It does compile in my template project though I can't guarentee that it will solve your problem.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for your help so far man. I copied/pasted your code and it threw just a couple errors (I edited my original post to show). Do I need to declare anything in my header file? (also attached in post).

Comment: I've posted what's in the template including the header file.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks man! If you don't mind, where can I find this template? For future use, it would be nice

Comment: @Nick: Also, does the code you provided enable lightweight migration?Just curious because I'm still learning the syntax. It's still giving me that error as well ("Can't merge two entities named data and data")

Comment: You can find that code if you create a new project, select the Navigation-Based Application, on the same screen check the "Use Core Data for Storage". Now look at the appDelegate.m. You can find the [Lightweight Migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweight.html) code in the documentation. What did you change in your model? The type of a property?

Comment: @Nick: This is a Mac App (I changed <UIApplicationDelegate> to <NSApplicationDelegate> above - a couple warnings still showed up, but it ran. Is it still relevant (no UIKit in Mac Apps)? And the code in the documentation (the one I posted originally) doesn't work without some editing like you said earlier? For my model (new version) I simply added one more attribute (binary) and changed the type of two other attributes from strings to binary (to allow font attributes). The names are untouched. The code above still throws the error (Can't merge two entities). I appreciate your help and patience