# Need a little help understanding Apple's documentation on Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I'm reading Apple's "Core Data Snippets" document (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/stack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008283-SW1), and I'm a bit confused at this part.

```
To create a new managed object context, you need a persistent store coordinator.

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = <#Get the coordinator#>;
NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[newContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];

If you already have a reference to an existing context, you can ask it for its persistent 
store coordinator. This way you can be sure that the new context is using the same 
coordinator as the existing one (assuming this is your intent):

NSManagedObjectContext *context = <#Get the context#>;
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [context persistentStoreCoordinator];
NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[newContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
```

Most specifically the <#Get the coordinator#> and <#Get the context#> parts. What exactly does that mean and what should go there in an actual application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, the Managed Object Context is almost like a scratchpad on which you make your changes, and then persist that scratchpad to storage. Pretty much every time you want to put a managed object in to storage, you need a context for it, so always make one when you're about to do so. I'm not very familiar with the PSC, but from the looks of it, you would only need one, and that one can be used by multiple contexts. If you want the same PSC to be used throughout your application, then I guess you can put it in a singleton or pass it around somehow so you don't have to make a new one every time.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm just starting to understand that, but what I'm specifically trying to figure out in this documentation is what <#Get the coordinator#> means in this code-snippet. Obviously something is supposed to go there instead, perhaps a method call of some sort. I just wish they gave an actual example.

Comment: Gotcha. Well for the context, this is what you do:
    coreDataAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication    sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

Not sure about the PSC. [This](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_iOS_5_iPhone_Databases_using_Core_Data) is what I did to learn how Core Data works. It might be of help to you as well.

Comment: And [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525349/where-to-put-code-configuring-persistent-store-for-migration) should explain the PSC.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a good read. The application I'm trying to make (just for practice) is a Cocoa application so I'm not sure how different the behavior is. I'm trying to get the managedObjectContext from the Appdelegate in an additional window controller, and the compiler keeps complaining that there's no known class method for the selector (even though it's declared clear as day in the Appdelegate.m file). I am importing AppDelegate.h in my view controller too. So I'm lead to believe that the view controller needs it's own ManagedObjectContext. This is where I'm hitting a brick wall.